# How many regions can my ios application monitor (simultaneously)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, geofencing

How many regions can my ios application monitor (simultaneously)? 
I read that the number of regions is 20, but not if it refers to 20 simultaneous regions

I can monitor a region that is being monitored by another ios application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is 20. That means you can be monitoring for 20 regions at one time. You have no access to regions in other apps. [From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringForRegion%3a):

> An app can register up to 20 regions at a time. In order to report region changes in a timely manner, the region monitoring service requires network connectivity.